# How to fill a stl::map by iterating to maximum value?

Tags: c++

I have an `std::map`, and I use the following method for filling up to the maximum value of the supplied data type. In this case, if `K` is `int` then the maximum value is `2,147,483,647`. I want my map to have `2,147,483,647` keys with the same value.

The below loop is very inefficient. Is there any method to reduce the time consumption?

```
for (auto i = keyBegin; i!=numeric_limits<K>::max(); i++) { 
    m_map[i] = val;
}
```

Comment: But why? You realize it will cost a **lot of memory**, and can easily go out of memory, right!

Comment: @PraneethPeiris: A few GB, nothing outside the capabilities of a reasonable PC.

Comment: i want to reduce the time consumption, is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: Assuming `K` the last value in that loop filled with be for `i = numeric_limits<K>::max() - 1`.   For a typical 32-bit int, that will not fill entry `2147483647`.

Comment: @Peter is right - a `do {...} while(i++!=numeric_limits<K>::max())` loop would work. Note: that's `i++`, not `++i`.

Comment: @MSalters how optimistic is your estimate regarding allocation overhead?

Comment: @MaxLanghof: If you mean the "several GB", I expect about 32 bytes per node (assuming `sizeof(void*)==8`) so 64 GB in total. A decent workstation PC supports at least 4x16GB memory, typical servers can have 256GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the code above is that you're inserting 2 billion numbers, all at the end of the map. But `operator[]` has no idea that you'll be inserting a new item there!

`std::map::insert(hint_before, value)` is what you need. You've got a perfect hint - all values will be inserted directly before `m_map.end()`

Comment: @Ron: You can see that SatckOverflow has no Intellisense  ;)

Comment: How do i keep track of the hint? i set the hint auto  it = m_map.upper_bound(i);  am i doing any thing wrong?                                                                               
  for (auto i = keyBegin; i!=numeric_limits<K>::max(); i++) { 
                        auto it = m_map.upper_bound(i);
                        m_map.insert(it, pair<K, V>(i, val)); 
                        cout << i << endl;
                    }

Comment: @NFA: That is entirely missing the optimization - the `upper_bound` is an O(logN)  search, and the result it gives you is always `m_map.end()` so there wasn't a need to search for it anyway. You know `i` isn't yet in the map. (The map was empty beforehand, right? Since you said "fill" not "overwrite")

Comment: Try `auto it = m_map.end();` and note that for `std::map` no iterators or references are invalidated on insertions, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: Tried it, i could see a improvement of speed than before.

Comment: @NFA: I think the Markdown parser ate a bit of your comment. To escape special characters, use `\`<backticks like this>\``

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the existing answers, this is really not a good use of `std::map`.

Maps are designed for quick lookup in a collection of keys & values, where the keys are "sparse". They're generally implemented as trees, requiring lots of dynamic allocation, tree rebalancing, and the sacrifice of cache locality. This is worth it for the general map use case.

But your keys are far from sparse! You literally have a value for every possible number in the key's type's range. *This is what arrays are for*.

Use an array and you will benefit from cache, you will benefit from constant-time lookups, and you will not need any dynamic allocation inside the container. You will of course need to dynamically allocate the container itself because it is *huge*, so, you're looking for `std::vector`.

And that's only if you really *need* to precalculate all these values. If you don't necessarily need them all multiple times, consider generating them on-demand instead. Because, regardless how much RAM a contemporary PC can provide you, this feels a bit like an abuse of the technology.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement MSalters's answer, that suggests to use `map::insert(hint, {key, value})` construct, I suggest to use  a non-default allocator. A specialized allocater can further speed up the insertion twofold. Consider the following trivial allocator:

```
template <class T>
class chunk_allocator
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        union
        {
            node *next;
            char element[sizeof(T)];
        };
    };
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using is_always_equal = std::false_type;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;
    T*allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        if (n > 1)
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * n));
        if (!m_free_head) populate();
        node * head = m_free_head;
        m_free_head = head->next;
        using node_ptr = node*;
        head->next.~node_ptr();
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&head->element);
    }
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) {
        if (!p)
            return;
        if (n > 1) {
            ::operator delete((void*)p);
            return;
        }
        node * new_head = new ((void*)p) node;
        new_head->next = m_free_head;
        m_free_head = new_head->next;
    }
private:
    static constexpr unsigned NODES_IN_CHUNK = 1000;

    void populate()
    {
        if (m_free_head) return;
        m_chunks.emplace_back();
        for (node & entry : m_chunks.back()) {
            entry.next = m_free_head;
            m_free_head = &entry;
        }
    }

    std::list<std::array<node, NODES_IN_CHUNK>> m_chunks;
    node * m_free_head = nullptr;
};

template< class T1, class T2 >
bool operator==( const chunk_allocator<T1>& a, const chunk_allocator<T2>& b )
{
    return (void*)&a == (void*)&b;
}
template< class T1, class T2 >
bool operator!=( const chunk_allocator<T1>& a, const chunk_allocator<T2>& b )
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

And its use:

```
std::map<int, int, std::less<int>,
         chunk_allocator<std::pair<const int, int >>> m_map;
```

Working 100,000,000 elements takes (on windows with cygwin):

- std::allocator:  Insertion: 7.987,  destruction: 7.238
- chunk_allocator: Insertion: 2.745,  destruction: 1.357

On Linux the differences are not that big, but still 2x improvements are possible.

Bonus points - the `chunk_allocator` takes less memory, since it does not use `operator new` for individual `map` nodes. Each call to `operator new` has to maintain memory management bookkeeping, which `chunk_allocator` does not have to.